# What does an exclamation mark (!) before a statement do?

Tags: syntax, jupyter-notebook

I was trying to install the dark theme in Jupyter notebook by typing this in notebook

```
pip install jupyterthemes
jt -t chesterish
```

The first command worked but I got some error in the 2nd one. Then I wrote this

```
!jt -t chesterish
```

And it worked. What did the exclamation mark do?

P.S. I am extremely new to python, just started last week

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of exclamation and question marks in Jupyter notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53498226/what-is-the-meaning-of-exclamation-and-question-marks-in-jupyter-notebook)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Any command prepended by exclamation point is run by your operating system shell instead of python. `jt` is actually a separate app called by your shell.

Comment: the link you mentioned is not public.