# What is the difference between " !pip install " and " pip install "

Tags: python, numpy, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I just updated my jupyter notebook using conda and tried to import numpy library

```
import numpy as np
```

but it was an error with message

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Then I tried to install packages thinking it is needed after an update in jupyter notebook using

```
pip install numpy
```

It was an error with message

```
"C:\.....path" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file
```

Then I found somewhere on web asking to use

```
!pip install numpy
```

And it worked

**My question being what did "!pip install numpy" do differently compared to "pip install numpy"**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53498226/what-is-the-meaning-of-exclamation-and-question-marks-in-jupyter-notebook

Comment: Read documentation on 'shell commands' in jupyter notebook.

Comment: You can't directly run terminal commands in a notebook. You need to use the magic command `%system` for that. `!some_command` is just an alternative to that

Comment: It means run it as a shell command rather than a notebook command