# Whenever I run '!pip list' or some command inside jupyter notebook it returns '& was unexpected at this time.'

Tags: python, windows, powershell, jupyter-notebook, conda

I'm using a conda (miniconda3) env. Inside my conda env I've Jupyter Notebook.
If I run some command from the notebook it returns `& was unexpected at this time.`.

[image: & was unexpected at this time.]

`%pip list` also shows the same result

[image]

> Some Info:
> OS: Windows 10;
> Python Version: 3.9.15 ( miniconda3 )

I didn't find any good solution.
I'm expecting to have that command executed.

Answer (score 0):

Please see here for detailed anwser:
[What is the meaning of exclamation and question marks in Jupyter notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53498226/what-is-the-meaning-of-exclamation-and-question-marks-in-jupyter-notebook)

What `!pip` is doing in your case is:

`cmd> pip`

and pip is not a valid windows cmd command.

What you're looking for might be:

`%pip list`

edit: this is my guess, I don't have a windows computer here to test this

Comment: tried that too..  same result

Comment: What happens, if you run `!dir`? Which is a cmd command. And stupid questions, as this is somehow strange, have you try rebooting everything and restarting jupyter? I never has same issues with pip inside jupyter on my windows machine.

Comment: yeah.. nothing works... I guess there's something wrong with Powershell or cmd

Comment: I think I've to reset the windows

Comment: I think in part what Ravnclaw is trying to steer your towards when pip does work on your machine is that for using it inside a notebook, for best practice, you want to now use the magic version in general and not with an exclamation. Same for `conda`, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). Separately `ls` alone should work because automagics is on generally by default and works for a lot of commands recognized. So the `%` gets added behind the scenes, I think. But Windows can be a problem. Maybe better in WSL?

Comment: @Wayne exactly. But what puzzles me, is, that he is saying that his jupyter is running inside the conda on windows. I assume, he followed the official installation: https://jupyter.org/install where pip is used. So my guess would be, that somehow conda or how he starts the conda environment might be the issue.
On my homeoffice machine, I also use conda inside windows and not WSL. Within the conda cmd, there is pip available (and within jupyter lab respectively)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, Ravnclaw. I don't use Windows for development so I was hoping WSL may make `pip` accessible. Also, glad you pointed out the conda thing. I should have mentioned (for others reading), if using Anaconda, stick with conda as much as you can for installations. Only use pip for the packages conda cannot install. The environments will be more robust and portable. And good point about being puzzled, Ravnclaw. It's all quite weird. Since OP is using minoconda, I figure OP is a power user and didn't suggest switching to the full Anaconda distribution; however, it may help.